# How to scroll multiple tableview simultaniously

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uiscrollview, parallel-processing

2 `Tableviews` in a `ViewController` with different size of cell height. When i scroll on the `view controller` , need to scroll both `tableview cell` at same time also both table cells also need to hide at same time.

`200px height` of cell in top tableview, `50px height` of bottom tableview.

when i swipe 100px , top table cell scrolls 100 px and bottom table cell should be scrolled 25px.

is this parallel scrolling any possible? any suggestion..
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As `UITableview` is derived from `UIScrollview` you can get the scroll amounts in the delegate method

```
- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
```

You can get content offset of the scrollview which is being scrolled and assign that to the other tableview.

In this method you should be able to access both tableviews.

The property you need to check is contentOffset.

```
firsttableview.contentOffset = scrollview.contentOffset
```

Comment: Thanks,  I have used the delegate you have mentioned and now both tableviews scrolling simultaneously with same px height. May I know how to change the content offset size, for scrolling as 200 px in first table and  50px in second table.

Comment: firsttableview.contentOffset = scrollview.contentOffset+200 try this.

Answer (score 3):

You can use this function of `UIScrollView` to scroll multiples `UITable`s parallel

```
func scrollViewDidScroll(scrollView: UIScrollView) {

    if scrollView == tableView1 {
        self.tableView1.contentOffset = CGPointMake(0, scrollView.contentOffset.y)
        self.tableView2.contentOffset = CGPointMake(0, scrollView.contentOffset.y)
    }
    else if scrollView == self.tableView2!
    {
        self.tableView1.contentOffset = CGPointMake(0, scrollView.contentOffset.y)
    }
    else if scrollView == self.bottomMenu_grid!
    {
        print(scrollView.contentOffset.x)
        self.tableView2.contentOffset = CGPointMake(scrollView.contentOffset.x, scrollView.contentOffset.y)
    }
}
```